# Finding the minimum delta stretching for a spring to creating enough force to fly the object below it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, spring

I directly dive into the question

[image]

My teacher ask me to do this question, I could not understand some parts. If you can explain me rather than solving it, I appreciate.

1. At the question it says that the spring relaxed length is $l$ which confused me since the spring already has an mass on it, which makes it impossible to make it relaxed length (The definition of the relax length is the length of a spring without any external force on it.).
2. If we call the object up is $A$ and object down is $B$ can we say that $m_A\cdot g=-kl$ since the object either not falling down or going up.
3. For the free body diagram of $B$ there is $m_B\cdot g=N$ (the normal force). I figured out that minimum stretch must be the stretch that makes the value $N$ is 0. So I try to use the equation $-kl$ but since we do not know the actual relax point (one which there is no object on it). It is impossible to find the stretch up value.

Probably we will use the conservation of the energy but I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

The equations work regardless is there is a mass on the spring or not. if with the mass on, it stops at an equilibrium point, that is where your new equilibrium point is measured. so f=-kx where x is measured from the equilibrium point.

The idea on how to solve this is to recognise that the force on one mass, is the same in magnitude but opposite direction for the other mass ( imagine a thought experiment where in one scenario you move one mass, and in the other scenario you move the other, it's the same scenario so each mass experiences an equal but opposite force, application of netwons laws)

when I compress the spring, the top mass experiences a force -kx, and the bottom mass experiences a force kx -> e.g, when x = -1 then the force on the top mass is upwards  and the force on the bottom mass is downwards,

Now, clearly the condition on whether or not the bottom mass leaves the floor, is whether or  not the force on the bottom mass due to the spring exceeds the force of gravity

Now for a thought experiment, when I compress the spring  it stored some potential energy, which via the conservation of energy, when the spring decompresses and extends, the maximum extension of the spring will have the same displacement as before from equilibrium, only in the positive direction. this means that the force on the spring at this moment is time is f =-k(-x) where x is the original displacement, its (-x) as this is represents the displacement on the opposite side of the equilibrium
.due to reasoning mentioned above  the bottom mass experiences the negative of this force,

f=k(-x)

if x is negative as in  a compression, then this force one the mass has reached the top, is directed upwards causing the bottom mass go upwards  provided this force is greater than the force of gravity in this situation

Mg<k(-x)

x=-mg/k

Which is the minimum displacement to make the lower mass go off the ground

(I think, someone correct me if I'm wrong )

Comment: Please render your formulas in Mathjax: https://www.mathjax.org/